# how to do searching from a bulk amount of data in java

Tags: java

Actually there is more than 12000 records getting fetched from database and displayed pagewise using pagination. And now I have a search box in UI which will search from all the records(near about 12000) across all pages. But this is taking sometimes to search from this huge record.

Could you please help me how can I make this search faster.

Comment: Hashmaps ? Also try adding your solution/approach to the question.

Comment: Talk is cheap, show us the code!

Comment: 1) 12000 records is peanuts, even for a toy database. 2) Make it faster by issuing a query which will fetch what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider these options:

- Instead of searching after you fetched all of them, make an intelligent query that will reduce the amount of candidates. Maybe your situation is so simple that your query can represent the full search?
- Multithreaded searching.

  - Split your 12000 blocks of data into the amount of available processor cores (by using `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`) and launch a Thread for each block that will do the job.
  - If your searching is heavy per object, you might want to see if there is a possibility to do a cheaper search method. Maybe by only looking into a couple of important fields only. Make sure that the job can be done quickly. In another Thread, you could do the deeper search and add results as they were found.
- This option is rather hard to do, but you could implement a technique that searches for candidates while the user is still entering the search words. Every three characters they types, filter the current set of candidates. This would allow you to filter from 12000 to maybe 4000 and for the next three chars only 100 left, etc. This, of course, depends on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

There is many way to do search.

1) SQL Search, here you can use the same sql statement that fetched the 12000 records and appends where clause using java code. here we prefer to search for the Indexed fields or u can add index in the DB level on the searchable fields.

2) Full Text Search, there is some technology that allows you to index your records as Full Text Index, you can read more about this [here](http://lucene.apache.org/)